# Using \VerbatimOut in a \newcommand -> FancyVerbError

Tags: verbatim, tcolorbox, fancyvrb

I'm creating a class for exercices with questions and answerdocument.
I have a command `\question{}` in which I write the question. And I create a box associated at the question in which the student write the answer. This box is at the end of the document, in a new page, in order to separate the questions and the answerdocument when printing.

Here is an minimal example of the class I'm creating.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage[theorems,breakable,skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{multido}




\newcounter{question}[section]
\newcommand{\question}[1]{\noindent\stepcounter{question}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,colback=black!10!white,arc=0mm,toprule=0mm,leftrule=0mm,rightrule=0mm,bottomrule=0mm,after skip=0.2cm,before skip=0.2cm,bottom=0cm,top=0cm,left=0cm,right=0cm]
        \textbf{Q\thequestion \ :} \textit{#1}
    \end{tcolorbox}}





\newcounter{docanswer}[section]
\newcommand{\docanswer}[1]{\stepcounter{docanswer}
        \begin{tcolorbox}[enforce breakable, break at=20cm/0cm,pad at break=1mm,enhanced,colback=yellow!10!white,fonttitle=\bfseries,underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\draw[help lines,step=2mm,white!95!black,shift={(interior.north west)}](interior.south west) grid (interior.north east);\end{tcbclipinterior}},arc=0mm,toprule=0.5mm,leftrule=0.5mm,rightrule=0.5mm,bottomrule=0.5mm,after skip=0cm,before skip=0cm,bottom=0cm,top=0cm,left=0cm,right=0cm]\textbf{Q\thedocanswer :\ }
            #1
        \end{tcolorbox}}



\newcommand{\answerdocument}{
            \newpage
            \multido{\numero=1+1}{\thequestion}{\docanswer{\input{answer_document_\numero.tex}}}
        }



        %% Command to minimise the code
\newcommand{\AD}[1]{
            \begin{VerbatimOut}{answer_document_\thequestion.tex}
                #1
            \end{VerbatimOut}
        }


\begin{document}

            \question{This is a first question}
            \begin{VerbatimOut}{answer_document_\thequestion.tex}
                This is the answer document for the first question
                \vspace{3cm}
            \end{VerbatimOut}


            \question{This is a second question}
            \begin{VerbatimOut}{answer_document_\thequestion.tex}
                This is the answer document for the second question
                \vspace{4cm}
            \end{VerbatimOut}


            %% This works, but I want to create a command (\AD) in order to minimise the code

            %\question{This is a third question}    
            %\AD{This is the answer document for the third question
            %   \vspace{4cm}}

            \answerdocument

\end{document}
```

My problem is that I want to create a `\newcommand{AD}` in order to, as shown on the third question, avoid to type

```
\begin{VerbatimOut}{answer_document_\thequestion.tex}
\end{VerbatimOut}{answer_document_\thequestion.tex}
```

When I use my new command 
`\AD{This is the answer document for the third question}`, I have the

```
FancyVerbError
```

Here is the code with the error

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage[theorems,breakable,skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{multido}




\newcounter{question}[section]
\newcommand{\question}[1]{\noindent\stepcounter{question}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,colback=black!10!white,arc=0mm,toprule=0mm,leftrule=0mm,rightrule=0mm,bottomrule=0mm,after skip=0.2cm,before skip=0.2cm,bottom=0cm,top=0cm,left=0cm,right=0cm]
        \textbf{Q\thequestion \ :} \textit{#1}
    \end{tcolorbox}}





\newcounter{docanswer}[section]
\newcommand{\docanswer}[1]{\stepcounter{docanswer}
        \begin{tcolorbox}[enforce breakable, break at=20cm/0cm,pad at break=1mm,enhanced,colback=yellow!10!white,fonttitle=\bfseries,underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\draw[help lines,step=2mm,white!95!black,shift={(interior.north west)}](interior.south west) grid (interior.north east);\end{tcbclipinterior}},arc=0mm,toprule=0.5mm,leftrule=0.5mm,rightrule=0.5mm,bottomrule=0.5mm,after skip=0cm,before skip=0cm,bottom=0cm,top=0cm,left=0cm,right=0cm]\textbf{Q\thedocanswer :\ }
            #1
        \end{tcolorbox}}



\newcommand{\answerdocument}{
            \newpage
            \multido{\numero=1+1}{\thequestion}{\docanswer{\input{answer_document_\numero.tex}}}
        }



        %% Command to minimise the code
\newcommand{\AD}[1]{
            \begin{VerbatimOut}{answer_document_\thequestion.tex}
                #1
            \end{VerbatimOut}
        }


\begin{document}

            \question{This is a first question}
            \begin{VerbatimOut}{answer_document_\thequestion.tex}
                This is the answer document for the first question
                \vspace{3cm}
            \end{VerbatimOut}


            \question{This is a second question}
            \begin{VerbatimOut}{answer_document_\thequestion.tex}
                This is the answer document for the second question
                \vspace{4cm}
            \end{VerbatimOut}


            % This works, but I want to create a command (\AD) in order to minimise the code
            \question{This is a third question}
            % Begin of my problem
            \AD{This is the answer document for the third question
                \vspace{4cm}}
            % End of my problem             
            \answerdocument

\end{document}
```

Comment: `tcolorbox` can save the content of the box itself, there's no need to use `verbatimout` etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a version with `tcbverbatimwrite` from `tcolorbox` -- there's no need to load another `verbatim` package, since `tcolorbox` is already active.

Inside of `\AD` the `\end{tcbverbatimwrite}` should be a string rather than the token `\end{tcbverbatimwrite}`, so `\scantokens{...}` is necessary.

This code does not work however for the `VerbatimOut` approach.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[theorems,breakable,skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{multido}

\usepackage{xparse}


\newcounter{question}[section]
\newcommand{\question}[1]{\noindent\stepcounter{question}%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,colback=black!10!white,arc=0mm,toprule=0mm,leftrule=0mm,rightrule=0mm,bottomrule=0mm,after skip=0.2cm,before skip=0.2cm,bottom=0cm,top=0cm,left=0cm,right=0cm]
    \textbf{Q\thequestion \ :} \textit{#1}
  \end{tcolorbox}
}


\newcounter{docanswer}[section]
\newcommand{\docanswer}[1]{\stepcounter{docanswer}%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[enforce breakable, break at=20cm/0cm,pad at break=1mm,enhanced,colback=yellow!10!white,fonttitle=\bfseries,underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\draw[help lines,step=2mm,white!95!black,shift={(interior.north west)}](interior.south west) grid (interior.north east);\end{tcbclipinterior}},arc=0mm,toprule=0.5mm,leftrule=0.5mm,rightrule=0.5mm,bottomrule=0.5mm,after skip=0cm,before skip=0cm,bottom=0cm,top=0cm,left=0cm,right=0cm]\textbf{Q\thedocanswer :\ }
    #1
  \end{tcolorbox}
}



\newcommand{\answerdocument}{%
  \newpage
  \multido{\numero=1+1}{\thequestion}{\docanswer{\input{answer_document_\numero.tex}}}
}



%% Command to minimise the code
\newcommand{\AD}[1]{%
  \scantokens{\begin{tcbverbatimwrite}{answer_document_\number\value{question}.tex}
      #1
    \end{tcbverbatimwrite}
  }%
}


\begin{document}
\question{This is a first question}
\AD{%
  This is the answer document for the first question
}


\question{This is a second question}
\AD{%
  This is the answer document for the second question
}

\question{This is a third question}
\AD{%
  This is the answer document for the third question
}
\answerdocument

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative approach to answer the question.

The `tcolorbox` package supports the saving of lower box parts into files. So, here the answers are written after `\tcblower`. For this, an environment should be used.

The saving is done by

```
savelowerto=answer_document_\thetcbcounter.tex,
```

To hide the lower part use

```
lowerbox=ignored,
```

As a further addition, I use the *recording* features of `tcolorbox` by

```
record={\string\docanswer{\thetcbcounter}},
```

This remembers that such an answer was given and should be used afterwards.

Finally, `\tcbstartrecording`, `\tcbstoprecording` and `\tcbinputrecords` are used to start and stop recording and loading the result.

The whole document is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[theorems,breakable,skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\newcounter{question}[section]

\newtcolorbox[use counter=question]{question}[1][]{%
  breakable,colback=black!10!white,
  arc=0mm,toprule=0mm,leftrule=0mm,rightrule=0mm,bottomrule=0mm,
  after skip=0.2cm,before skip=0.2cm,bottom=0cm,top=0cm,left=0cm,right=0cm,
  fontupper=\itshape,
  before upper={\textbf{\upshape Q\thetcbcounter\ :\ }},
  lowerbox=ignored,
  savelowerto=answer_document_\thetcbcounter.tex,
  record={\string\docanswer{\thetcbcounter}},
  #1
}

\newcommand{\docanswer}[1]{%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,break at=20cm/0cm,pad at break=1mm,enhanced,
    colback=yellow!10!white,fonttitle=\bfseries,
    underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\draw[help lines,step=2mm,white!95!black,shift={(interior.north west)}](interior.south west) grid (interior.north east);\end{tcbclipinterior}},
    arc=0mm,toprule=0.5mm,leftrule=0.5mm,rightrule=0.5mm,bottomrule=0.5mm,after skip=0cm,before skip=0cm,bottom=0cm,top=0cm,left=0cm,right=0cm]
      \textbf{Q#1\ :\ }
      \input{answer_document_#1.tex}%
  \end{tcolorbox}}

\newcommand{\answerdocument}{%
  \newpage%
  \tcbinputrecords%
}

\begin{document}

\tcbstartrecording

\begin{question}
  This is a first question
\tcblower
  This is the answer document for the first question
  \vspace{3cm}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
  This is a second question
\tcblower
  This is the answer document for the second question
  \vspace{4cm}
\end{question}

\tcbstoprecording%

\answerdocument

\end{document}
```